# What's a British English way of saying rest stop

Tags: synonyms, british-english

Context:

> Are we staying here the whole night, or is this just a [rest stop].

I don't feel as though I'd say rest stop in British English, but I can't think of what I could say exactly.

Comment: A pause, probably.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. To confirm, are you asking about the break itself (which in American English might colloquially be called a *pit stop* or *bathroom break*) or an area or facility where one might take such a break, which might be a *rest stop*, *rest area*, *truck stop*, *service area*, or *travel plaza* depending on the area and the type of amenities offered?

Comment: I'd expect the term 'short rest' (short in comparison to an overnight stop: up to 2 hours say).

Comment: I'm asking about the break itself. I guess I could use 'short rest' but I was hoping for something more colloquial

Comment: @Netanya The term 'comfort stop' is used in car travel to denote a stop for leg-stretching, tea drinking, and bathroom use.

Comment: You could say **breather**, which is an informal term for a short rest.

Comment: An example of British usage might be "We'll pull over into a lay-by for a short while".